# How to dynamic eval and register component at Nuxt server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I try to register a component from a remote API on the server side. I dont know how to parse the component string and register it as a normal imported component.

Currently, I have tried eval and vm like

```
Vue.component('dynamic-component', async (resolve) => {
  const componentStr = await this.$api.getComponent()
  const component = eval(componentStr)
  // const component = vm.runInNewContext(componentStr, {vue: require('vue')})
  resolve(component)
})
```

But both ways fail on the client side since it lacks fs and other modules.